# Decrease symbol's box without changing its graphical view

Tags: letterspacing

I need to make symbols borders tighter and closer to each other.
But I don't want to make symbol smaller or taller with `\scalebox{}[]`.

For example: It must be looking like A, but the next symbol must starts in the middle of A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a box half the width of the character:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\half}[1]{\makebox[.5\width][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}

x\half{A}\half{B}\half{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whoa, can you explain what `\width` does and how it works? I can't seem to `\show` it and it's not listed in [this command glossary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary).

Comment: @WChargin When in the context of `\makebox` (or `\framebox`, or `\savebox`) one can use `\width`, `\height` and `\depth` in the width optional argument, which refer to the natural width, height or depth of the material. Also `\raisebox` can profit of them: `\height` and `\depth` are for this, of course.

Answer (score 4):

```
\makebox[0pt][c]{A}
```

is an A that takes up no space, centred on that zero size box, change the width or alignment to fit your needs.